# Moving elements gradually around a web page

Tags: javascript, css, html

Like in the stackoverflow question editor, if you select Links / Images / Lists / Code etc, an explanation box appears and the editor text box in which I'm typing now, gradually moves up and down depending on where it needs to move.

How is this achieved? I looked at the page source but the editor seems to be some sort of Javascript component.

Thanks!

Comment: No clue what you're talking about.

Comment: @Walkerneo me neither. All I see is a regular tooltip on the toolbar icons in the edit window.

Comment: lol obviously I failed at explaining. I mean, even in this comment box, if you press "help" a little help box gradually pops out, when you press "hide help", it gradually moves and disappears... see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [JQuery Javascript Toolkit](http://www.jquery.com). It is used widely to extend Javascript capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, the slide in slide out effect is what I guess I was looking for :)